# G-string ring on guitar

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar

I play an American Fender stratocaster. Whenever I play a note on the g string and take my fingers off of it, the open g rings out very loud (when playing through my amp at a loud volume). I can palm mute the string or mute it with my right hand, but this is somewhat tedious. Is this a setup problem with my guitar, or is this just a normal aspect of playing electric guitar that I have to come to terms with? When I say ring, it just sounds like I picked an open g.

Comment: Is this only happening with this particular guitar ?

Comment: Does changing the EQ setting on the amp (e.g. setting bass to 10, mids and treble to 0) reduce this phenomenon at all? It might be a feedback issue.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you are unintentionally "pulling off" when removing your fingers.  To address this I would look at (a) playing the piece very slowly and making sure that you smoothly remove your finger from the string and (b) trying to find comfortable an smooth ways to use your fret hand fingers to dampen the string.
If other surrounding notes allow this, it could even be the finger that had been fretting the g-string.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Dave's answer, if you're absolutely sure that it's not your technique causing the problem (other people don't have the same problem on your guitar, or you play other guitars without this problem), you can increase the action of your G string (i.e raise the G string's saddle a little).